# How to convert dynamic html to pdf?

Tags: java, html, pdf

I want to convert dynamic html to pdf. Following code show the conversion of static html to pdf:

```
Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:/sample/pdfaskkea.pdf"));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,new FileInputStream("webcontent/jsp/index.jsp"), null); 
        
//        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,new FileInputStream("C:\\pdf_table1.html"), null);
        //step 5
        
        
         document.close();
 
        System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
```

Comment: `XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml` parses XHtml. It does **not** execute Java server pages code. Thus, you need to install the `index.jsp` on a web application server (e.g. Tomcat) and then query that server using the address used for the page; this way you'll retrieve the generated Html page which you finally can feed into `XMLWorkerHelper`.

Answer (score 2):

From your question it is not clear, what you mean under "dynamic HTML".

If it is an HTML dynamically created with JSP, for example, [PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/reference.htm#6.1) offers a JSP custom tag library - you only need to surround your code with   and  to output PDF instead of HTML.

If under dynamic HTML you mean JavaScript-rich HTML pages, I would recommend to take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), which can convert HTMLs also built on-a-fly with JavaScript. PhantomJS is a native standalone application, based on WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itext pdf library to convert html into rich PDF files. To generate dynamic HTML content you can use a template library like thymeleaf.

I have a detailed article about [generating PDF files with thymeleaf in a spring boot](https://springhow.com/spring-boot-pdf-generation/) application if you are interested.